# How to store the environment of a ggplot into a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating various plots in a for loop and storing them in a list. The idea is that the user of the script simply needs to provide a dataframe and that the script automatically performs a barplot for each column of that dataframe. The problem is that I am employing a dynamic code, so if the environment of each step of the loop is not stored in the list, then when I call each element of the list I get always the same plot (which corresponds to the last column of the dataframe).

Here is a test dataframe:

```
test<-data.frame(color=c('blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'green'),
                 fruit=c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'blueberry', 'orange'),
                 letter=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B','C','C'))
```

And here the loop that I am trying to do:

```
plotList<-list()

for (i in 1:ncol(test)){
  varName<-colnames(test)[i]
  
  newPlot<-ggplot(data=test,aes(x=test[,varName]))+
    geom_bar()
  
  plotList[[i]]<-newPlot
  
}
```

The problem is that I always get the same plot when printing `plotList[[1]]`, `plotList[[2]]` or `plotList[[3]]`

I have also thought about employing apply, but in my real script I have to create some intermediate dataframes inside the for loop, so it is not so straightforward. I also tried `recordplot()` but it didn't work. Do you know if there is a way not only to store the plot in a list, but also the environment from the step in which the plot was created?

Comment: Using `lapply()` often resolves such problems for me. However, `aes(x=test[,varName])` seems risky to me. It might be better to use `aes(x = .data[[varName]])` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option could be using the `!!` with `sym` to use your quoted variable varName like this:

```r
plotList<-list()
library(ggplot2)
for (i in 1:ncol(test)){
  varName<-colnames(test)[i]
  
  newPlot<-ggplot(data=test,aes(x=!!sym(varName)))+
    geom_bar()
  
  plotList[[i]]<-newPlot
  
}
plotList
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Please check this chapter [Quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .data[[varName]] to index, (as its recommended)

```
library(ggplot2)
plotList<-list()

for (i in 1:ncol(test)){
  varName<-colnames(test)[i]
  newPlot<-ggplot(data=test,aes(x=.data[[varName]]))+
    geom_bar()
  plotList[[i]]<-newPlot
}
```

However first it would be easyier to just take the colnames as iterator:

```
# use colnames as iterator 
# benefit this safes x name.

for (var in colnames(test)) {
  append(
    plotList,
    ggplot(data=test,aes(x=.data[[var]]))+
      geom_bar()
  )
}
```

This results in the correct xlabel titles : color , fruit,
letter

You could also just use lapply , since dataframes are lists of columns:

```
plotList <- lapply(test,\(x) ggplot(data=test,aes(x=x))+geom_bar())
```

you dont have to preassign a list, since lapply outputs a list, also you dont have to specify an iterator, since it will default use coulmns.